# Convert JSON.pretty_generate() in Accordion view format

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, json

In my `rails` application, the JSON file is dynamically generated via the controller. Now I am rendering it with `render :json => JSON.pretty_generate(@xml_hash), :status => :ok` it is coming in tree like structure

```
{
  "hotel_inventory": {
    "xmlns": "http://www.example.com/abc",
    "type": "update",
    "hotel_id": "12",
    "room_type_id": "13",
    "room_inventories": {
      "room_inventory": [
        {
          "from_date": "15/02/2018",
          "to_date": "18/02/2018",
          "applicable_days": "ALL",
          "inventory": "5",
          "release_hours": "0"
        },
        {
          "from_date": "19/02/2018",
          "to_date": "19/02/2018",
          "applicable_days": "ALL",
          "inventory": "4",
          "release_hours": "0"
        },
        {
          "from_date": "01/03/2018",
          "to_date": "31/03/2018",
          "applicable_days": "ALL",
          "inventory": "5",
          "release_hours": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want it in the collapsible format (Accordion view) I tried many things but not getting any success.

Comment: I dont get why you are doing this. It would the responsibility of the requester to make it pretty (for instance browsers have plugins to make json pretty out of raw source)

Comment: @apneadiving okay but after pretty how to make it collapsible

Comment: What's "collapsible format"?

Comment: @Niklas like 'Accordion View'

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **browser** plugin like 
[Json-Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa) to display your json-response in the browser like this.

Comment: thanks but this is chrome plugin which is installing in my browser it will not work on other PCs

Comment: If you want to display the json in readable format, you must return html which you can style with css and js to look like your desired result